# Flux waitFor() and async operation, how to model.

Tags: reactjs, pouchdb, reactjs-flux

I'm using pouchDB as a local database for an app. I want to query the results from PouchDB and load this into React.js. However, even though I'm using the waitFor() method the results of PouchDB query return too late. I think I don't understand the use of waitFor() correct, maybe someone can shed a light on it.

I have two stores, the DbStore that retrieves data from the datbase. And the FileExplorerStore this store is used by my react components.

```
DbStore.dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register(function (payload) {

    var action = payload.action;
    var folder = payload.action.folder
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'OPEN_FOLDER':    
            if (folder === 'start') {
                DbStore.init();
            }
            else {
                DbStore.createPath(folder);
            }
            DbStore.emitChange();
            break;
        default:
        // do nothing
    }


    return true;
});
```

The DbStore has a function LoadFiles that will load the DB files into the _files array. For illustrative purposes I've copied the code below:

```
loadFiles: function (_path) {
            var fileNames = fs.readdirSync(_path);
            _files = [];


            fileNames.forEach(function (file) {
                console.log(file)
                db.query(function (doc) {
                    emit(doc.name);
                }, {key: "bower.json"}).then(function (res) {
                    _files.push(res.rows[0].key)
                });
            });

 },
```

The FileExplorerStore had a method to retrieve the files from the _files array. Then in the FileExplorerStore I have a getFiles() method, that will retrieve these files. However, this array is always empty because this method will be executed before the array is filled.

FileExplorerStore

```
FileExplorerStore.dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register(function (payload) {

var action = payload.action;


switch (action.type) {

    case 'OPEN_FOLDER':
        AppDispatcher.waitFor([DbStore.dispatchToken]);

        FileExplorerStore.emitChange();
        break;
    default:
    // do nothing
}


return true;
});
```

In react.js the getInitialState function will call the getFiles() function from the FileExplorerStore to display the files.

How can I fix this or model this in a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `waitFor` in the `dispatcher` released by the Facebook team was not designed for that (at least the release on Sep 11, 2014), it just make sure the `dispatchToken` (which passed to `waitFor`) was executed and returned, and then it will starts executing the next registered callback.

So in your case this is somehow the correct expected behaviour.

What i will do is separate the action into two parts. First is fetching, second is `OPEN_FOLDER` as in `FileExplorerStore`. Assuming the DBfetch action named `DB_FETCH`, this will trigger your database and then get the data into `_files`, in the fetch success callback, trigger an `action` to the `OPEN_FOLDER`. For the trigger point, it is depends on you how you want to design it, i would have the third action named `INIT_OPEN_FOLDER` which trigger the DB_FETCH, then show the loading indicator to the UI, and finally when get the emit from `OPEN_FOLDER`, only display the data

Comment: Thanks. It seems like your explanation is the right way to model this. I also checked the #reactjs IRC and they also advices to call an action in my Async fetch callback. I did however changed to Reflux because in Reflux I can call my Database API from Actions, and after the data is fetched execute the next action.

Comment: @ChinKang may you look here pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537568/flux-waitfor-specific-event